# Background color through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to put `background-color` in paragraph through jquery before this i create div and there is two buttons show and hide when click on show div displayed and when click on hide div is hide .. so after this when i try this background-color not visible

check this code

```
<head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnhide").click(function () {
                    $("#dvmain").hide("slow");
                });
                $("#btnshow").click(function () {
                    $("#dvmain").show("slow");
                });

            }); 

            $document.ready(function () {

                $("p").css("background-color", "red");

            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnshow" value="show" />
        <input type="button" id="btnhide" value="hide" />
        <div id="dvmain" style="width:100%;height:400px;background-color:red;">

        </div>

        <p>this is paragraph one</p>
        <p>this is paragraph two</p>
        <p>this is paragraph three</p>

    </body>
```

any solution?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to tell what is your problem here. Could you rephrase the question? Providing a jsfiddle would be nice too :)

Comment: What do *you* think the problem is? Why do you have `$(document)` in one place, and then `$document` in the place that doesn't work, did you think to use `$(document)` in both places, or just place everything inside the first one.

Comment: oh means we use $(document) only once?

Comment: @Bakhtawar Can you justify why you have removed the accepted answer from mine?

Comment: i can not remove i think :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#btnhide").click(function () {
      $("#dvmain").hide("slow");
   });
   $("#btnshow").click(function () {
      $("#dvmain").show("slow");
   });
   $("p").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

And remove this part

```
$document.ready(function () {
    $("p").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: thanku so much ...  when i use this $("#secondp").css("background-color", "black","font-color","white");  background color is black but text color is not white .. how i done this

Comment: @Bakhtawar When you want to specify multiple css property you should specify it as an object like this `$("p").css({"background-color": "black", "font-color": "white"});` instead of this `$("#secondp").css("background-color", "black","font-color","white"); `.

Comment: now i have a button when i click on button then background change can change for this i use this  $("#btone").click(function () {
                    $("#firstp").css("background-color", "purple");
                    $("#secondp").css({ "background-color": "black", "font-color": "white" });
                    $("#thirdp").css("background-color","green")

                })

Comment: and html code.. <input type="button" id="btone" value="hello"/>
        <p id="firstp">this is paragraph one</p>
        <p id="secondp">this is paragraph two</p>
        <p id="thirdp"> this is paragraph three</p>

Comment: but when i click on button black background color is display but font color not change .. and i want font color change on clicking button

Comment: There is no attribute `font-color` you should use `color` instead. Try this `$("#secondp").css({ "background-color": "black", "color": "white" });`

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("p").css("background-color", "red");
                $("#btnhide").click(function () {
                    $("#dvmain").hide("slow");
                });
                $("#btnshow").click(function () {
                    $("#dvmain").show("slow");
                });

            }); 

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnshow" value="show" />
        <input type="button" id="btnhide" value="hide" />
        <div id="dvmain" style="width:100%;height:400px;background-color:red;">

        </div>

        <p>this is paragraph one</p>
        <p>this is paragraph two</p>
        <p>this is paragraph three</p>

    </body>
```